# What type of amazon ec2 instance should i take ? And how many of them?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, node.js, redis

I will be hosting a website . Our initial target will be around 50,000 unique visitors a day . Files are served using apache/php and the realtime events (likes,comments) are handled using a nodejs server . Also i am using redis as key-value store alongside mysql , for conventional relational data storage . In the worst case scenario i might have 2000 concurrent users and around a 400 of them uploading photos (5mb size at max) . Also in the future i would have to implement a recommendation system in the back end using user activity history for which i may need additional amount of storage and compute power .

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to decide up front on a particular size that will work for you, I'd suggest you architect a solution that allows you to scale. This gives you a lot more resilience and redundancy as a bonus.

An Elastic Load Balancer with one or more servers behind it is cheap and easy to set up, and you can size the instances to suit or fire up (or shut down) servers automatically as the load varies with AutoScaling.